# Nested class doen't change enclosing class field

Tags: java, inner-classes, static-classes

I try to write simple program, which works with nested class. I have noticed, that nested class can not change (or I did mistake) enclosing class field:

```
public class MyClass {

    private boolean bool = false;
    private NestedClass nestedClass = new NestedClass();

    private class NestedClass {

        private void print(){
               System.out.println(bool);
        }

        NestedClass(){
            bool = !bool;
        }
}

    MyClass(){
        nestedClass = new NestedClass();
    }

    public void getInfo(){
        nestedClass.print();
    }
}
```

After creating of new instance of `MyClass`, `bool`'s value doesn't change:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.getInfo();
}
```

Output is `false`. But I expected `true`.
What I did wrong?

Comment: You are calling the `NestedClass` constructor twice, so it will twice change the value of `bool` `false -> true -> false`. You could add a sysout to the `NestedClass` constructor to see this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it did, the reason you're still seeing the value of bool as false is because its getting set twice (negated twice).

Once here

```
private NestedClass nestedClass = new NestedClass();
```

and second time

```
MyClass(){
    nestedClass = new NestedClass();
}
```

Both call the constructor of NestedClass twice which negates it twice resulting in `false`->`true`->`false`.